# How can I defimply for multiple modules at the same time? (macro attempt not working)

Tags: elixir

I need all of my models to implement a particular protocol. My current attempt is a `MyApp.Convert`module with this macro defined:

```
defmodule ConvertMacro do
  @moduledoc """
  All model structs need to implement the convert interface and must be added
  here.
  """

  defmacro defimpl_convert_for(modules) do
    Enum.map(modules, fn module ->
      quote do
        defimpl Units.Convert, for: unquote(module) do
          require Units

          def to_standard_metric(struct) do
            Units.to_standard_metric_for_struct(unquote(module), struct)
          end

          def to_user_data(struct) do
            Units.to_user_data_for_struct(unquote(module), struct)
          end
        end
      end
    end)
  end
end

ConvertMacto.defimpl_convert_for([MyApp.User, MyApp.Block])
```

error:

```
== Compilation error on file lib/protocols/units_convert.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function ConvertMacro.defimpl_convert_for/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * defimpl_convert_for/1

    ConvertMacro.defimpl_convert_for([UdioDb.Block])
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

(the error message is actually a bit redundant)

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do, or do I just have to type it all out?

Comment: Can you please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least include the surrounding code and also the error messages? It's hard to figure out what exactly went wrong when we don't know how you called this macro and what the error was.

Comment: @Dogbert posted full code with error

Comment: (Note that you can pass a list to `defimpl` too: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/03a7d744cc1ce7c3820ee60cafcf71b1bc7d5211/lib/elixir/test/elixir/protocol_test.exs#L183-L185)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually much simpler since `defimpl` supports it natively:

```
defimpl FooProtocol, for: [Foo, Baz, Bar] do
  def protocol_function(x, y, z) do
    @for.some_function(x, y, z)
  end
end
```

The `@for` module attribute allows you to access the module that the protocol is implemented for. You can see examples in here: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/date_time.ex#L650-L662

Comment: omg I have the biggest crush on this language <3 (and shame on me for not reasong the RTFM)

Comment: @o_o_o-- discover utf8, Elixir deserves ❤❤❤ rather than just <3